# Google Cloud App Engine : Custom WordPress theme and plugins missing

Tags: php, wordpress, git, google-app-engine

Following this [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible) and using the `flex` environment with `php 7.2`, I am trying to deploy to App Engine with custom plugins and themes.

These themes are not available on `wppackagist`, given that they are truly custom to my project.

My git repo is correctly saving the custom plugins and themes -- all `composer.json` based `wppackagist` plugins are being installed as intended.

However, for the life of me, I cannot get the deploy to include my custom files.  I have additionally verified that the image uploaded to AE is the correct version, and it has been promoted to serve all traffic as intended.

Can anyone help me understand the logic that I am missing to ensure that when I deploy my app that the custom plugins and themes are built into the image?

Comment: Did you use the `--verbosity` option to increase the `gcloud app deploy` verbosity in order to determine exactly if the files of interest are indeed ignored and, if so, for what reason?

Comment: Verbosity is not a valid argument:

```ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) argument --verbosity: expected one argument
Usage: gcloud app deploy [DEPLOYABLES ...] [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --bucket | --help | --image-url | --promote |
                         --stop-previous-version | --version
```

Comment: `--verbosity=info` added; note that `--verbosity` by itself has no output nor does it show up in the CLI help output.. anyhow ;)

The build correctly ignores all of the /vendor/* paths.  However, it does not mention skipping anything in `wp-content`.

My wordpress app folder was named `wp_app`. Changing it to `app` per the log output which says `Step #1: Step 2/8 : ENV DOCUMENT_ROOT '/app/wordpress'` even though I configured my app as `wp_app`

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is to not change the `app` output folder.  Via the CLI install helper, I defined the output folder to `wp_app` -- it still anticipated `app` as the folder.  Nothing was in the `app` folder when I created the service as `wp_app` being the WordPress folder.  So, just keep the folder structure as-is and you will be fine.